# Изменение значений геймпада

Tags: python

В общем, нужно изменить читаемые с геймпада показания.

Есть такой код:

```
while 1:
 events = get_gamepad()
 for event in events:
     print(event.state)
```

в print'е, если стик стоит в центральном положении - выводится "1792", в крайнем левом - "-32768", в крайнем правом - "32767".

Нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы в центральном положении значение было "90", в крайнем левом - "180", а в крайнем правом - "0" (естественно, что значения должны равняться положению стика, то есть, к примеру, чем ближе к центру от правого края, тем значение ближе к 90 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 и так до 90, то есть до центра), в право аналогично, чем ближе к центру - тем значение ближе к 90 (180, 179, 178, 176 и так до 90). Надеюсь, объяснил понятно)

Comment: Арккосинус, вестимо.

Comment: @D-side, я слышал, что "в военное время значение синуса/косинуса может достигать четырёх, а то и пяти", но чтобы `32767` - это слегка перебор, по-моему... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU подумаешь, на коэффициентик домножить.